# Lock free non-allocating collection

Tags: collections, pool, intrinsics, lock-free

I am looking for a *collection* data structure that is:

1. thread safe
2. lock free
3. non-allocating (amortized or pre-allocated is fine)
4. non-intrusive
5. not using exotic intrinsics

Element order does not matter. Stack, queue, bag, anything is fine. I have found plenty of examples that fulfill four of these five requirements, for example:

- .NET's [List](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Generic/List.cs) is not thread safe.
- If I put a mutex on it, then it's not lock free.
- .NET's [ConcurrentStack](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentStack.cs) is thread safe, lock free, uses a simple `CompareExchange`, but allocates a new `Node` for each element.
- If I move the `next` pointer from the `Node` to the element itself, then it's intrusive.
- [Array based lock free data structures](https://www.cse.yorku.ca/~niloo/resources/MScthesis.pdf) tend to require multi-word intrinsics.

I feel like I'm missing something super obvious. This should be a solved problem.

Answer (score 1):

- .NET's [ConcurrentQueue](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentQueue.cs) fulfills all five requirements. It does allocate when the backing storage runs out of space, similar to `List<T>`, but as long as there is extra capacity, no allocations occur. Unfortunately the only way to reserve extra capacity upfront, is to initialize it with a collection of same size and then dequeuing all the elements.
- same is true for .NET's [ConcurrentBag](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/sys/system/collections/concurrent/ConcurrentBag.cs)